# How do I dynamically create an Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> predicate with string parameter?

Tags: c#, expression, predicate

I have the follow C# classes

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> Phones  { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsMobile { get; set; }
}
```

Below is a sample Expression I'm trying to create dynamically.

```
Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> isMobileExpression = p => p.Phone.First().IsMobile;
```

I would like to create an Expression like the one above but dynamically define the "p.Phone.First().IsMobile" expression instead of hardcoding it.
For example :

```
var paraName = "p => p.Phone.First().IsMobile";
Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> isMobileExpression = p => paraName;
```

Is that possible to do? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Perhaps a `Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Contact, bool>>>` containing property names and respective Expressions? If it's really dynamic, you may need to compile it with Roslyn

Comment: Hi, what you want to actually achieve with that? you want to set up differents regular expressions to check mobiles phone dynamically ?

Comment: I plan to create a utility function with this code that takes a parameter and return the build expression that is used in another function.

Comment: Charlieface, can you provide an example on how to compile with Roslyn? Thanks.

Comment: Might be a case for DynamicLinq though not sure how the parser would handle First() as I've never used it

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a [CSharpScript](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Scripting):

```cs
public class Contact
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsMobile { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var code = "return Phones.First().IsMobile;";   
    var script = CSharpScript.Create<bool>(code, globalsType: typeof(Contact), options: ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences("System.Linq").WithImports("System.Linq"));
    var scriptRunner = script.CreateDelegate();
    Console.WriteLine(scriptRunner(new Contact() { Phones = new List<Phone> { new Phone {IsMobile = true }}} ));    
    Console.WriteLine(scriptRunner(new Contact() { Phones = new List<Phone> { new Phone {IsMobile = false }}} ));   
}
```

#### UPD

If you want an expression, you could wrap the `ScriptRunner` delegate into `Expression.Call()` like so:

```cs
Expression<Func<Contact, Task<bool>>> GetExpression()
{
    var code = "return Phones.First().IsMobile;";
    var script = CSharpScript.Create<bool>(code, globalsType: typeof(Contact), options: ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences("System.Linq").WithImports("System.Linq"));
    var scriptRunner = script.CreateDelegate();
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Contact));
    var mi = scriptRunner.Method;
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Contact, Task<bool>>>(Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(scriptRunner.Target), mi, p, Expression.Constant(CancellationToken.None)), p);
}
```

then you would compile and use it as you see fit:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var scriptRunner = GetExpression().Compile();
    Console.WriteLine(scriptRunner(new Contact() { Phones = new List<Phone> { new Phone { IsMobile = true } } }));
    Console.WriteLine(scriptRunner(new Contact() { Phones = new List<Phone> { new Phone { IsMobile = false } } }));
}
```

I however feel that this is a bit too convoluted. Would probably be easier if you could use the delegate directly.

Comment: timur, thanks for the example above. However, it is not giving me the type I wanted which is Expression<Func<Contact, bool>>. What can I change to get the right return type? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: you might note that it's meant to run asynchronously so the return type is `Task<bool>` but i suppose you could craft an expression that would await for result if need be